# How to make a field required for customers but not for administrators in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I made a custom field in prestashop.

I would like to know if there is some way to make this field only required on the frontend and not for administrators.

this is my code in Customer class

```
array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING,  'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want it to be required for customers but not required when an admin creates a customer? Because if you just want to make it optional (ie "not required") just remove the `'required' => true` part :P

Comment: but if I remove required, will be not required for users

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a quick way to make this possible exactly as you want it, so here are two suggestions:

1 - Remove the `'required' => true` from the definition and create some kind of custom validation like `if (Tools::getValue('type ') == "") { return false; }` in an override of the front office AuthController (Warning: code is completely untested and should definitely be improved, also according to your particular PS version).

2 - Use frontend validation by giving the frontend form field the `required` attribute (you should do this even if oyu use 1)